# How can I limit each user to just one like per page?

Tags: php

I have a liking system, a bit like what facebook have. However, users can like pages as many times as possible.. How can I limit it to just one for each user like per page? The code I have is:

```
<?php
    session_start() ;
    $conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");
    $p_id = $_GET['post_id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM forum WHERE post_id = $p_id");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE forum SET likes=likes+1 WHERE post_id = '$p_id'") ;
    ?>
    <?php
    header("Location: forum.php?id=".$row['post_id']);
    die();
    ?>
```

Comment: facebook has a user login system.. you need that first

Comment: I have that. I have a users table with user_id, username ect... But I don't know how I would be able to only allow one like per page for each user.

Comment: the `SELECT` query appears to be completely unused, so can be removed

Comment: It is used for the header function, isn't it? Without it, the redirect doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Thats basic logic error, `$row['post_id']==$p_id` so you can just use `$p_id` instead and ditch the `SELECT`

Comment: I didn't realise that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to track the user. Make a table with userid and postid

Comment: I have a separate users table with a userid field. Could I connect the two tables somehow?